# Help with Magento 2 extension conflict for configurable product swatches

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, extensions, swatches, conflict

I am using two extensions which both appear on the product page (configurable product with swatches):

1. MagicZoomPlus - for image zoom ability
2. Amasty Out of Stock notifications - for the ability to allow customers to sign up to be notified when a particular option, which is currently out of stock, becomes available. When clicking on such an out of stock option, the extension causes an email sign up form to appear for this notification.

The issue is that the Amasty extension is not being called when clicking on an option when the MagicZoomPlus extension is enabled.

I am far from proficient in Magento 2 code, but I believe the issue arises from the MagicZoomPlus extension's layout override below:

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.options.wrapper">
        <block class="MagicToolbox\MagicZoomPlus\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable" name="product.info.options.configurable" as="options_configurable" before="-" template="Magento_ConfigurableProduct::product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml"/>
        <block class="MagicToolbox\MagicZoomPlus\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable" name="product.info.options.swatches" as="swatch_options" before="-" />
</referenceBlock>
```

The second block above seems to override the default Magento 2 block for swatches which the Amasty Out of Stock extension needs to work:

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.options.wrapper">
        <block class="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable" name="product.info.options.configurable" as="options_configurable" before="-" template="Magento_ConfigurableProduct::product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml"/>
</referenceBlock>
```

How can this be solved? I have at this for quite some time so any help you can provide would be most useful and sincerely appreciated.

Thank you for your time and expertise.

Comment: Could you post your MySQL error log (last 400 lines) after one of these situations?  There may be clues on contributing factors.